# Sqlite - How to remove substring in a field using wildcards

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to remove all occurrences of a certain string pattern across all fields in a table.

For example, find all occurrences of the pattern `"<XY>*<Xy>"` where `*` represents any possible configuration of characters. I want to remove just those substrings and leave the remainder of the string intact.

This is an example of what I would like to use as my SQL command, but of course this doesn't work:

`UPDATE Table SET Field = replace(Field, '<XY>*<Xy>', '');`

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option which attempts to splice around the `<XY>...</XY>` tags:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Field = SUBSTR(Field, 1, INSTR(Field, '<XY>') - 1) ||
            SUBSTR(Field, INSTR(Field, '</XY>') + 5)
WHERE Field LIKE '%<XY>%</XY>%'
```

It updates fields containing this pattern with the concatenation of everything coming before the first `<XY>` and everything coming after the second `</XY>`.

Note that I used `<XY>...</XY>` rather than what you had originally, because `INSTR()` is not case sensitive, and both tags would appear as being the same thing.

## Demo

The demo is for MySQL but the sytnax is almost identical to SQLite.

Comment: I didn't ask my question correctly, lol, but you did answer what I asked and I was able to use your answer to do what I actually wanted to do. Thanks!